# Electrons and Atomic Mass

Tags: energy, periodic-table

Is the mass of electrons covered when talking about atomic mass. For example, the mass of Carbon is $12.011\space\text{amu}$. If this is including the mass of electrons (assuming the atom is neutral) the nucleus' mass is $12.011-6(\frac{1}{1840})=12.00773913$

The reason I need to know is I'm studying mass defect in relation to protons and neutron. If I inadvertently include electrons in my calculation, my binding energy will also be wrong.

Comment: Good question. The mass of electron is so small relative to neutrons/protons that it can be neglected in binding energy calculations. Electron mass in amu is 0.00054. You can try both approaches and see the differences.

Comment: Note that 12.011 amu is the weighted isotope average mass. The mass of a neutral carbon-12 atom in the ground state (electronic and nuclear) is 12.0 amu (exactly), defining the amu. So, yes, it includes the mass of the 6 electrons.

Comment: (And, it is kind of funny that this was asked by a user named 'Dalton' - you'd think they would know their own definition!).